# Escaping double quotes in .csv

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, escaping

I have a .csv file which has values like

```
Abc,3/4"×3/4"
Paper,Blue,2"
Abc 45 xyz 3/4""
```

The issue is when I open it in notepad these values become

```
"Abc,3/4""×3/4"""
"Paper,Blue,2"""
"Abc 45 xyz 3/4""""
```

These extra double quotes around double quotes cause trouble for me to upload my file in an application which accepts only .csv file.

Is there any way that I can display these values as they are without extra double quotes in notepad?

```
"Abc,3/4"×3/4""
"Paper,Blue,2""
"Abc 45 xyz 3/4"""
```

Comment: "The issue is when I open it in notepad these values become" - it has nothing to do with OPEN or NOTEPAD, those double quotes are already added when you save the file. Depending on the tool you use to save the file you might be able to change "string delimiter". Also the pattern you show seems to be the standard way to "skip delimiter", could you please specify which tool you use to open the file and confirm it has a problem processing it?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I am using Microsoft excel to open the .csv file. Due to the double double quotes, the application in which i want to upload my file reads  "Abc,3/4"×3/4"" as "Abc,3/4" only. Thats why I don't want these two double quotes.

Comment: When I create your example and open in Excel 365 it just opens as you expect, which is the app giving you wrong results? "Is there any way that I can display these values as they are without extra double quotes in notepad?" - the way you see them in notepad IT'S THE WAY HOW DATA IS ACTUALLY STORED IN CSV.

Comment: @MátéJuhász im using Microsoft excel 2010 to save the file. Open it using notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real standard for a csv file.  [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) is published but "*It does not specify an Internet standard of any kind*"

When MS Excel (and many other programs) generates a text/csv file, it uses double quotes as a text specifier, so that commas, linefeeds, double quotes within a field will be treated literally.

Short of using VBA, one method would be to

- replace the double quotes with some other character (eg tilde `~`);
- Generate the csv file
- then use a text-editor (eg notepad, notepad++) on the resultant file to replace the other character with the double-quote,
- then send it to your program that apparently doesn't recognize this feature of csv files.

Comment: I had a value as ```Abc 45 xyz 3/4""```. When replaced all double quotes with @ or ~ . For this value the original doubles quotes were removed. Normally it should be displayed as ```"Abc 45 xyz 3/4@@"```. But it was displayed like ```Abc 45 xyz 3/4@@```.

Comment: @Anonymous You wrote in your question that your values looked like `Abc 45 xyz 3/4"` and you wanted in a CSV the same way (i.e. only a single double quote). Now you are commenting that your original values look like `Abc 45 xyz 3/4""` and you really want it to be `Abc 45 xyz 3/4@@"`  It is hard to hit a moving target.  Please edit your original question to reflect your real problem with realistic data.

Comment: i edited and also included this example but my file is filled with many random formats which use double quotes

Comment: @Anonymous Given your edit, and assuming your original data is being viewed in excel, before applying my fix, do a `find/replace` of all double double quotes with a single double quote.